# Switching from Nashorn to Rhino (Gradle)

Tags: java, gradle, java-8, rhino, nashorn

I'm using Java 8 with Kotlin and one of the libraries in my project (http://michel-kraemer.github.io/citeproc-java/) refuses to run on the Nashorn JavaScript interpreter bundled with Java 8. The solution is to use the Rhino JavaScript interpreter instead.

I'm using Gradle to build my project. I've already added Rhino to my dependencies, but the library still insists on using Nashorn.

```
compile 'org.mozilla:rhino:1.7.7.1'
```

Furthermore the following code produces a NullPointerException:

```
val m = ScriptEngineManager()
// specifically look for "rhino" engine
val engine = m.getEngineByName("rhino")
```

So it seems that Rhino is not on the classpath anywhere. How do I make sure Rhino is available to my application?

Answer (score 2):

Rhino based jsr223 engine is no longer shipped with jdk8+. But, you can follow the steps documented here to get Rhino engine on jdk8+ -> https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Using+Rhino+JSR-223+engine+with+JDK8

That said, we'd like to know why nashorn cannot be used! Please do file a bug or send issue report to nashorn-dev openjdk alias.

Comment: Thanks. I sent an email to the mailing list.

Answer (score 2):

Along with Rhino engine you will need JSR-233 bridge (as it is no longer in JDK). You can use following maven dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mozilla</groupId>
        <artifactId>rhino</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cat.inspiracio</groupId>
        <artifactId>rhino-js-engine</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then you just call right script engine:

```
new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("rhino");
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll find this quite helpful.

https://github.com/mozilla/rhino/releases/tag/Rhino1_7_13_Release

It appears now you can add the additional `'org.mozilla:rhino-engine:1.7.13'`  in order to make the engine available, provided it's in your classpath.